SharePoint List Form Customize Body Set Section Height
Good afternoon,
I have a site where users can select all their training for various tasks.  It all works great except on the input form, when users have a lot of certifications, the text of that field spills out into the sections above and below it.  For the red marked area (see image link): Ideally the form sections would grow to accommodate, or truncate the text...
For the blue marked area, Ideally the one choice that is really long would be truncated at the edge of the column...   (see image link)

Any ideas how to rejig this to make this work?  Seems like JSON for the body is very limited, but possibly there are other lines of attack?
Any help is really appreciated.
Header:
{
"elmType": "div",
"txtContent": "Add/Edit Roster",
"style": {
"height": "40px",
"font-size": "18px",
"font-weight": "600",
"padding": "10px",
"color": "#fff",
"background-color": "#008080"
}
}
Body:
{
"sections": [
    {
        "displayname": "1. Staff information",
        "fields": [
            "Staff Name",
            "Manager Name",
            "Branch / Region",
            "District / Section",
            "Status",
            "Branch/Work Center"
        ]
    },
    {
        "displayname": "2. Experience:",
        "fields": [
            "TCS and IMS Training",
            "Incident Management Team (IMT) Positions",
            "Are you assigned to an Incident Management Team",
            "Critical Functional Positions"
        ]
    },
    {
        "displayname": "3.  Availability:",
        "fields": [
            "Available To Be Rostered",
            "Management Support Availability",
            "Training Attestation",
            "End of Deployment Period",
            "Start of Deployment Period",
            "Homebase Office",
            "Blackout Dates / Periods",
            "Notes",
            "Staff Position",
            "Request for Assistance",
            "Title",
            "Attestation manager notice sent",
            "First Day Worked",
            "Deployment Location"
        ]
    }
]

}

looks like a bug to me. You will have more control if you customise the list form with PowerApps.

Could you please provide the JSON code you have used?

Sure; if you think it will help!  Done!
